# How do I stub node.js built-in fs during testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I want to stub node.js built-ins like `fs` so that I don't actually make any system level file calls. The only thing I can think to do is to pass in `fs` and all other built-ins as an argument to all of my functions to avoid the real fs from being used. This seems a little bit silly and creates a verbose function signature crowded with built ins as arguments.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

function findFile(path, callback) {
  _findFile(fs, path, callback);
}

function _findFile(fs, path, callback) {
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
     //Do something.
  });
}
```

And then during testing:

```js
var stubFs = {
  readdir: function(path, callback) {
     callback(null, []);
  }
};

_findFile.(stubFs, testThing, testCallback);
```

There's a better way than this right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I like using [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) for stubbing out require(...) statements

## Module Under test

module-a.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
function findFile(path, callback) {
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
     //Do something.
  })
}
```

## Test Code

module-a-test.js

```
var rewire = require('rewire')
var moduleA = rewire('./moduleA')
// stub out fs
var fsStub = {
  readdir: function(path, callback) {
     console.log('fs.readdir stub called')
     callback(null, [])
  }
}
moduleA.__set__('fs', fsStub)
// call moduleA which now has a fs stubbed out
moduleA()
```

Comment: +1 I usually have a custom `require` function for mocking out modules

Comment: Pretty cool but it bugs me a little that rewire uses Module.wrapper which is an undocumented, internal property on Module. Node could change that without updating the API version and all the tests would fail. :/

Comment: That is a little worrying. Also I have found rewire does not play nice with Mongoose models. That is less of an issue for me since I have been using couchdb more than mongodb lately but it is something to keep in mind

Answer (score 15):

Stubs are functions/programs that simulate the behaviors of components/modules. Stubs provide canned answers to function calls made during test cases.

An example can be writing a file, without actually doing so.

```
var fs = require('fs')

var writeFileStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'writeFile', function (path, data, cb) {  
 return cb(null)
})

expect(writeFileStub).to.be.called  
writeFileStub.restore()
```

Comment: This should be the classically-accepted answer in my opinion. The concept of a stub, rather than using `rewire` for reflection, is universal in testing. And there would be many libraries capable of offering the ability to stub something.

Comment: I don't see why this is not the most upvoted and accepted answer, since it's also the most hassle-free with fewest possible side-effects, since we only stub out expected parts.

Comment: This is the answer people!

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Here is the latest sinon format
```let writeFileStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'writeFile').callsFake(function (path, data, cb) {return cb(null)})```

Answer (score 14):

Rewire and other stubbing solutions are good if the module under test is the one making calls to `fs` itself. However, if the module under test uses a library which uses `fs` underneath, rewire and other stubbing solution get hairy pretty quickly.

There is a better solution now: [mock-fs](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs)

> The mock-fs module allows Node's built-in `fs` module to be backed temporarily by an in-memory, mock file system. This lets you run tests against a set of mock files and directories instead of lugging around a bunch of test fixtures.

Example (shamelessly lifted from its readme):

```
var mock = require('mock-fs');

mock({
  'path/to/fake/dir': {
    'some-file.txt': 'file content here',
    'empty-dir': {/** empty directory */}
  },
  'path/to/some.png': new Buffer([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]),
  'some/other/path': {/** another empty directory */}
});
```

Comment: I ♥︎ `mock-fs` now. Thanks for this answer. This is perfect for unit-testing my node file modules.

Comment: I've found that mock-fs is also problematic. It breaks require, logging, and native bindings.

Comment: mock-fs also breaks line numbering for jest/jest-ts: https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs/issues/226

Comment: mock-fs also does not work with the new fs.promises

Answer (score 11):

An alternative (although I think Noah's suggestion of rewire is better):

Write a wrapper around `require`, named `requireStubbable` or so. Put this in a module which you configure once, in test setup code. Because node caches result of require, whenever you require the requireStubbable module again, you'd get the same configured function. You could configure it so that any number of modules would be stubbed, all others would be passed on unchanged.

Any module which you'd want to support passing in stubs need to use the `requireStubbable` function instead of regular `require` though. The rewire module does not have that drawback, and instead gives control to the calling code.

#### Added April 26

I've never realized, but since the object (or more precisely: object reference) returned by `require("fs")` is cached, you could simply do:

```
const fs = require("fs")
fs.readFile = function (filename, cb) {
  cb(null, new Buffer("fake contents"));
};
// etc
```

When you include this code anywhere, `fs.readFile` will be pointing to the above function everywhere.
This works for stubbing out any module that is a mere collection of functions (like most built-in modules). The cases for which it doesn't work if the module returns a sole function. For this, something like `rewire` would be necessary.

Comment: I like your additional idea.  Quick and easy!

Comment: Never thought this would work, but I tried it and it did. Seems like a bit of a hack and I think it's better to be careful when using this so you don't accidentally overwrite the function where you really need it. But other than that, it's a very elegant solution and I like it better than solutions which require additional dependencies just to mock a single function.

Comment: re additional idea:  when it comes to tests, you should undo any changes you cause after a test is finished.  Otherwise, side effects of changes may cause subsequent tests to erroneously pass or erroneously fail.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version that works with the fs.promises api:

```
const fsMock = sinon.mock(fs.promises);
fsMock.expects('readFile').withArgs('test.json').returns(Promise.resolve(Buffer.from('{}')));

const val = await fs.promises.readFile('test.json');

expect(val.toString()).toEqual('{}');
fsMock.verify();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how i think of this:

The way you do it is the obvious first step but it sucks having to pass those things in everywhere— Callers of your functions shouldn't care that you want to test with mocks. You don't want to just overwrite or monkey-patch the global modules in the global namespace for your test. And the normal dependency injection model is pretty verbose in Javascript since there's no class-local scope.

So around the whole module, I've done like `(function(fs, net, http) { … })(fs, net, http);`

Then inside the module, if there's a class constructor, make the mocks optional extra parameters to the constructor (or possible properties of a single `mocks` object parameter or something) and your test passes in the mocks. Your constructor overwrites the real node modules within only the module's local scope.

Alternately if the module just has static functions; have one such function which initializes the mocks, you can validate that that function is not called in your prod code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [using-stubs](https://github.com/carlosouro/using-stubs), particularly at the [require()](https://github.com/carlosouro/using-stubs#require) part.

Leave you module code as you would do **normally**, eg:

```js
//myApp.js
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
  //Do something.
});
```

Then, on your tests module (or any unit testing framework), use **using-stubs** to modify (and even match or validate) the behaviour of **fs**:

```js
var using = require('using-stubs');

//get a reference to require('fs')
var fs = using.require('fs');

//override behaviour of fs.readdir
using(fs)('readdir').stub(function(path, callback){

    //override fs.readdir() logic
    var err = null;
    var files = [];
    // (...)

    //mock original behaviour
    callback(err, files)
})

//then run the app normally to test it (some frameworks do this for you)
require('myApp')
```

Now running your test will override the internal behaviour of **fs** in *myApp.js*, without needing to change code in either of the components.

You can also do other cool stuff such as validating how many times methods are called, match exact method call parameters or scope, even override behaviour on new Class instances used internally in *myApp.js*.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`memfs`](https://github.com/streamich/memfs) in-memory filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out mock-fs and fake-fs, which do a lot of this already.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('./myStubFs');
```

Would seem to be a big improvement.  Whatever solution you find will probably involve writing your own stub functions.  The ideal solution would be lower level so you don't have to touch all the files you want doing this, e.g. perhaps you want 3rd party libraries stubbed out as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me, mocking/stubbing a file is not needed, I usually create a temporary file in temporary folder.